# Is it possible to select text on a Windows form label?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, winforms, label

Is it possible to highlight/select part of text in a Windows Form label control? I know its possible with RTFtextbox control but that using that control would be overkill as I need to create many instances of the label.

Comment: What do you mean by "select"? You mean select it by code, to use this text after?

Comment: sorry @ John...by select I mean text-selection e.g. in RichTextBox you can use "SelectedText" etc properties to select/highlight a portion of the entire text. The effect is similar to selecting/highlighting text manually with mouse.

Comment: Just an idea: you could create a class derived from Label in which you have some property to store starting and ending index of text to be selected, then overriding onPaint event you can highlight text drawing a semitransparent rectangle over it

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Is it possible to select text on a Windows form label? - NO (At least no easy way without overriding Label.Paint method)

You can easily change a TextBox for this purpose.

```
TextBox1.Text = "Hello, Select Me";
TextBox1.ReadOnly = true;
TextBox1.BorderStyle = 0;
TextBox1.BackColor = this.BackColor;
TextBox1.TabStop = false;
TextBox1.Multiline = True; // If needed
```

Don't believe? here is an example for you.

[image]

**Option 2 (If you just want to enable copy label text)**

Double clicking on the label copies the text to clipboard. This is the default winforms Label functionality. You can [add a toolTip control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9776120/591656) to improve the usability if you like.

[image]

Comment: The issue you might run into is if you're setting the text of the texbox dynamically it will hide the text if it's wider than the textbox, unlike the label.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan you have to set «WordWrap» property to «true».

Comment: If needed, you can also set Multiline = True to be able to change the height of the TextBox.

Comment: While this is still a valid approach, I would recommend checking out @vmil's answer below (which is that the default functionality of labels is now that double clicking on a label copies the text).

Comment: The code may need to be changed if "\n" was used to create new lines in the Label; use "\r\n" in the TextBox instead;

Answer (score 22):

Double clicking on a label will copy the text to the clipboard. This is now the default behavior of Windows Forms labels.

Comment: This is one of those instances where time has changed what the correct answer is, but there's not a good way to go about making the answer more known.

Comment: This is quite a hidden feature, most users wouldn't figure this out, they would most likely select try to select the text and hit Ctrl+C.

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp In this instance you'd want to notify the user of the functionality.

Answer (score 16):

Like *Bala R* answered:

> "Use a TextBox with BorderStyle set to None and Readonly set to true
>   and Backcolor to match that of the container.".

If the Text string is very long, and the `Width` of the `TextBox` is not enough to display all text, then you can set the `Width` property of the `TextBox` to display all it's Text.

If you need to know the correct number for `Width`, then you can use the `MeasureString` method of `Graphics` for this. You can get the instance from `CreateGraphics()` method of the `Control` (`TextBox` in this case).

First parameter is TextBox's Text, and second parameter is TextBox's Font. This function returns `SizeF` struct. You need only the Width property of it, convert it to integer with `(int)size.Width` or `(int)Math.Round(size.Width)`.

Don't forget to call the `Dispose()` method of the graphics instance after, because you won't need it anymore.

---

You can write your own function that will do all this process:

```
static void SetText(TextBox textBox, string str)
{
   Graphics graphics = textBox.CreateGraphics();
   SizeF size = graphics.MeasureString(str, textBox.Font);
   graphics.Dispose();
   textBox.Width = (int)Math.Round(size.Width);
   textBox.Text = str;
}
```

Comment: If you have a fixed-width text box that you want to size the height of with this code, see this Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29299297/measure-text-height-wrapped-in-a-specified-width

Answer (score 8):

Use a `TextBox` with `BorderStyle` set to `None` and `Readonly` set to `true` and Backcolor to match that of the container.

Answer (score 7):

No, it's not possible to select text on the Windows Form Label. You can instead use a read only textbox for this.

Answer (score 3):

You will not be able to highlight part of the text on a label. However, you can use an image and set it to the Label.Image property if the text for these labels is static.

Comment: it'll be really tricky to implement, plus the text is dynamic - thats why the need to highlight some of it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is about selecting *parts* of the text of a label but I assume the text shall ultimately be placed on the clipboard.

So if you don't mind copying the whole text, just set a `Click` event on the label to copy its text to the clipboard:

```
myLabel.Click += new System.EventHandler(MyLabel_Click);

// ...

private void MyLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Clipboard.SetText(myLabel.Text);
}
```

Comment: Double clicking on a label will copy the text to the clipboard. This is now the default behavior of Windows Forms labels. There is no need to do this yourself.