# How can I add a hint or tooltip to a label in C# Winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, label, tooltip

It seems that the `Label` has no `Hint` or `ToolTip` or `Hovertext` property. So what is the preferred method to show a hint, tooltip, or hover text when the `Label` is approached by the mouse?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying tooltip on mouse hover of a text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873175/displaying-tooltip-on-mouse-hover-of-a-text)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You have to add a [`ToolTip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx) control to your form first. Then you can set the text it should display for other controls.

Here's a screenshot showing the designer after adding a `ToolTip` control which is named `toolTip1`:

[image]

Comment: Wow, that seems convoluted/counterintuitive, Yuck.

Comment: @ClayShannon In a way I suppose it is. But the design is somewhat elegant. Some controls will never want tool tips. This way, the `ToolTip` control can just register itself for mouse over events and display the proper text depending on the event raised. This all happens in the background.

Comment: I agree.  It also allows you to use the same tooltip control for multiple controls.

Comment: @MarkAinsworth  since one comment says it's good and one that it's bad, perhaps you state  whether you agree it's good or agree it's bad?  . I suppose you're saying you agree it's good.

Comment: I think this is a bad design because it only support a static tooltip.  How would you update the tooltip at runtime?

Comment: @ArvoBowen You'd access the `ToolTip` object and change its value there.  This can be done at runtime pretty easily.

Comment: Ahh I see, the answer was not 100% clear for me when I was first looking at it.  Thanks

Comment: I Think it worth to say that to add a tooltip you shoul toolTip1.SetToolTip(Control, "tooltip text here");

Answer (score 99):

```
yourToolTip = new ToolTip();
//The below are optional, of course,

yourToolTip.ToolTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
yourToolTip.IsBalloon = true;
yourToolTip.ShowAlways = true;

yourToolTip.SetToolTip(lblYourLabel,"Oooh, you put your mouse over me.");
```

Comment: Don't forget to dispose the tooltip if you do this a lot on each mouseover, you'll leak handles until the GC calls the finalizer on the older tooltips.

Answer (score 26):

```
System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip ToolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip();
ToolTip1.SetToolTip( Label1, "Label for Label1");
```

Answer (score 18):

just another way to do it.

```
Label lbl = new Label();
new ToolTip().SetToolTip(lbl, "tooltip text here");
```

Answer (score 5):

Just to share my idea...

I created a custom class to inherit the Label class.  I added a private variable assigned as a Tooltip class and a public property, TooltipText.  Then, gave it a MouseEnter delegate method.  This is an easy way to work with multiple Label controls and not have to worry about assigning your Tooltip control for each Label control.

```
    public partial class ucLabel : Label
    {
        private ToolTip _tt = new ToolTip();

        public string TooltipText { get; set; }

        public ucLabel() : base() {
            _tt.AutoPopDelay = 1500;
            _tt.InitialDelay = 400;
//            _tt.IsBalloon = true;
            _tt.UseAnimation = true;
            _tt.UseFading = true;
            _tt.Active = true;
            this.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(this.ucLabel_MouseEnter);
        }

        private void ucLabel_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs ea)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.TooltipText))
            {
                _tt.SetToolTip(this, this.TooltipText);
                _tt.Show(this.TooltipText, this.Parent);
            }
        }
    }
```

In the form or user control's InitializeComponent method (the Designer code), reassign your Label control to the custom class:

```
this.lblMyLabel = new ucLabel();
```

Also, change the private variable reference in the Designer code:

```
private ucLabel lblMyLabel;
```

Comment: But isn't Designer code regenerated every time user changes something using Form visual designer?

Answer (score 3):

I made a helper to make life easier.

```
public static class ControlUtilities1
{
    public static Control AddToolTip(this Control control, string title, string text)
    {
        var toolTip = new ToolTip
        {
            ToolTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.None,
            IsBalloon = true,
            ShowAlways = true,
            ToolTipTitle = title,
        };
        toolTip.SetToolTip(control, text);
        return control;
    }
}
```

Call it after controls are ready:

```
        InitializeComponent();
        ...
        linkLabelChiValues.AddToolTip(title, text);
```

It's an way to keep consistent tool tip styles.