# What is the equivalent of the Delphi "Hint" in C# Windows Desktop Forms applications?

Tags: c#, forms, user-interface, hint

I'm starting to work in C#, I've created a Windows desktop application, based on a `System.Windows.Forms.Form`, as follows: (automatically generated)

```
public partial class Frm_MyForm : Form
```

As I have some experience in Delphi (almost twenty years ago), I was expecting everything back in this form, but I don't find a `Hint` attribute, not on the form itself, nor on the text boxes, labels or buttons I added there.

Does anybody know if hints are foreseen in C# projects of my kind?

My Target .Net framework version is "4.6.1".

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know what "Hint" attribute might be for, but as of today, I would suggest, instead of Windows Forms, use WPF. Windows Forms are too much platform specific and limited in capabilities.

Comment: What do you expect this `Hint` to do? Would it be a [`ToolTip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: indeed, a Tooltip is what I mean, but I don't see the possibility to link to a tooltip in my form and its components.

Comment: Yes, in C# the Delphi Hint was renamed to ToolTip when porting the VCL to become the .NET Framework, and it's now a full object, a bit odd and not really intuitive to use I find.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a ToolTip to a control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339524/how-do-i-add-a-tooltip-to-a-control) and [How can I add a hint or tooltip to a label in C# Winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776077/how-can-i-add-a-hint-or-tooltip-to-a-label-in-c-sharp-winforms)

Comment: [Tooltip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tooltip-controls)  is a Windows control, not something provided by Delphi or Windows Forms. WinForms always supported tooltips through the Tooltip control. Check [How to: Set ToolTips for controls on a Windows Form at design time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-set-tooltips-for-controls-on-a-windows-form-at-design-time?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)