# Generate a label on button click in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I would like a label to be generated every time a button is clicked on my UserControl - below is the method called whenever the button is clicked:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

I would be grateful for a code snippet inside the method that will generate a label with my choice of text, location and tooltip.

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: `this.Controls.Add(new Label {Text = "something", Location = ...`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily in windows forms application. Following code snippet only generates a `label` at specific location with hardcoded text and some basic properties settings. You can modify it according to your requirement e.g. you can change `label name, location, text` accordingly. Hope this will be helpful for you.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var lblnew = new Label
            {
                Location = new Point(50, 50),
                Text = "My Label", //Text can be dynamically assigned e.g From some text box
                AutoSize = true,
                BackColor = Color.LightGray,
                Font = new Font("Microsoft JhengHei UI", 9.75F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)0)
            };
            //this refers to current form you can use your container according to requirement
            Controls.Add(lblnew);
        }
```

Or you can also use simplified initialization as follows;

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var lblnew = new Label
        {
            Location = new Point(50, 50),
            Text = "My Label", //Text can be dynamically assigned e.g From some text box
            AutoSize = true,
            BackColor = Color.LightGray,
            Font = new Font("Microsoft JhengHei UI", 9.75F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, (byte)0)
        };
        //this refers to current form you can use your container according to requirement
        Controls.Add(lblnew);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you - is there anyway to make the label invisible and only have a tooltip which can be seen when hovered over?

Comment: Yes you can do it by changing color and background of label. Can also hide this i.e. visible=false; You can also create tooltip for your control. For more information about creating tooltip do visit this 
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776077/how-can-i-add-a-hint-or-tooltip-to-a-label-in-c-sharp-winforms)

Comment: You are welcome. If it solves your problem then accept my [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)