# Measure text height wrapped in a specified width

Tags: c#, text, graphics

How can I calculate the height needed to render a text wrapped in a specified width?

I found the following method in `Graphics`

```
graphicsObj.MeasureString(text, font, width);
```

But it needs an instance of `Graphics` and at the time I have not graphics instance. In fact I prefer a static method to find the height. `TextRenderer.MeasureText(..)` could be an option but it lacks a parameter for proposed width.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The overload & flag you need is:

```
var size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, font, new Size(width, height), TextFormatFlags.WordBreak);
```

For accuracy you should really try to use one of the overloads that accepts a device context.

Comment: What is the height you passed to the Size constructor in the third parameter?

Comment: The heigh of the proposed render rectangle, pass 0 if you don't know or care

Answer (score 0):

```
var size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(FieldValue, InvoiceFont, new Size(105, 16), TextFormatFlags.WordBreak);
RectangleF rectF1 = new RectangleF(xProductName, CurrentY, size.Width, size.Height);
g.DrawString(FieldValue, InvoiceFont, Brushes.Black, rectF1);
```